# map marker on Unirgy storelocator in Magento

Tags: magento

How can I add a marker to the Google Map instance created via the Unirgy Store Locator in Magento.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added this within the `load:function`

```
var point = new GLatLng(xx,yy);
map.setCenter(point, 14); //set centre and zoom
var marker = new GMarker(point);
map.addOverlay(marker); //add marker
```

and it seems to have fixed the missing marker.